# django 1.9 and registration/login.html

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm working on a django 1.9 project.

With Django 1.7.7, login functionnalities was working, but now all the time I have : `registration/login.html : Template Does Not Exist`

The templates login.html, logout.html are present in 'webgui/template/registration/'  and I didn't modified them.

Here some of my settings.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'webgui',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'NCIS.db'),
}
}

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/login/'

LOGOUT_URL = '/logout/'


DIRS = (
    join(BASE_DIR, 'webgui/template/registration'),
    join(BASE_DIR, 'webgui/template/')
)
```

And my `urls.py` :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
import webgui.views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', login, name='login.html'),
    url(r'^login/$', login, name='login.html'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout.html'),

    url(r'^homepage/$', webgui.views.homepage),
    url(r'^addproject/$', webgui.views.addproject)
]
```

What's wrong?  I checked the Django docs, but that's the default behaviour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to put your template dirs paths in `DIRS` list inside `TEMPLATES` setting. (Anyway, your template folder name should be `templates` not `template`.)

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [join(BASE_DIR, 'webgui/template/registration'),join(BASE_DIR, 'webgui/template/')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Comment: I renamed my folder to `templates` , and added paths in `TEMPLATES` array, (even if  there is already a DIRS definition at the bottom.. )  ,  and it's working :)  Thanks.

Comment: The `DIRS` setting at the bottom of your settings has no effect. Django only looks at `TEMPLATES['DIRS']` in Django 1.8+. Now now that you have renamed your directory to `TEMPLATES`, the simplest config would be to set `'DIRS': []`, and remove `DIRS` from the bottom of the settings.

Answer (score 20):

This question appears first in search engine with searching for 
`registration/login.html : Template Does Not Exist`

So for those coming through search engine, please note that this template doesn't come by default with Django. If you haven't created it, that's why you are getting this error

Here is how you can create a simple one
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html

Answer (score 8):

After upgrading  my django to 1.9.1, same thing happened to me. Apparently, there are updates on templates directory.
Here is how I fixed it.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Of course you should have BASE_DIR defined

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

After that,I've deleted the templates folder and created a templates folder for each app. So, inside the each app, just create templates and put the html files inside.

Also in views, connect it to the  html file like this.

```
def index(request):
    context_dict = {}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context_dict)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You have set `'APP_DIRS': True,`, so Django will search for `templates` directories inside each app in `INSTALLED_APPS`, including your `webgui` app.

The problem is that you have named your directory `webgui/template/` instead of `webgui/templates/`, so the app loader won't find it.

The easiest fix is to rename your directory. If you don't want to do this, you'll have to add the `webgui/template` directory to your `DIRS` option.