# TemplateDoesNotExist, registration/login.html Django

Tags: django, django-templates

Am using Django Authentication Model.
The problem is when i visit /accounts/login, i get TemplateDoesNotExist: registration/login.html error message. Now the problem is i already specified a template for the LoginView.

Here is my accounts/urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views
app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('join/', views.SignupView.as_view(), name='join'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

The login template is located at accounts/templates/accounts/login.html

And here is the TEMPLATES

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

My projects urls.py file has these

```
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291167/django-1-9-and-registration-login-html may this help

Comment: Just print out the value of os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') and check if it matches your template folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your error message, it is expecting the `login.html` file is to be located within your `accounts` app `templates/registration` directory like this: `accounts/templates/registration/login.html`. That should fix your issue.

Also, add these two lines at the bottom of your `settings.py` file:

```py
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
```

Comment: This fixed my issue!
Do you know where I can find more info on why this is needed?

Answer (score 4):

I just create a 'registration/login.html' in accounts
as

```
{% extends "admin/login.html" %}
```

Full path : 'accounts/templates/registration/login.html'